# How to bind dynamic data to a table in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to bind dynamic data to a table created in xml. But I couldn't make it. I am not getting any errors but it always shows "No Data Available". Here is what I have tried.

App.view.xml :-

```
<sap.ui.layout:HorizontalLayout xmlns:sap.ui.layout="sap.ui.layout" id="table_layt">
    <sap.ui.layout:content>
        <Table noDataText="No Data Available" id="bud_table" class="table_layt">
            <items></items>
            <columns>
                <Column id="c1">
                <header><Label text="Account Description" id="aclab"/></header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="c2">
                <header><Label text="Actual" id="actlab"/></header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="c3">
                <header><Label text="Budget" id="budglab"/></header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="c4">
                <header>
                <Label text="Variance" id="valab"/></header>
                </Column>
            </columns>
        </Table>
</sap.ui.layout:content>
```

App.controller.js :-

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("bud_table"); 
var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells:[
        new sap.m.Label({
        text:"{AccountDesc}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
        text:"{AmtActFore}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
        text:"{AmtBudget}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
        text:"{AmtVariance}"
        })
        ]
});
```

oTable.bindItems("/root", oTemplate);

And my data looks like this :-

data

Object {root: Array[64]}

```
root: Array[64]

  0: Object

    AccountDesc: "blah"

    AccountNo: "blah"

    AmtActFore: "blah"

    AmtBudget: "blah"

    AmtVariance: "blah"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the part where you're pushing the data into a model:

```
this.getView().setModel(
    new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        root: [{
            AccountDesc: "blah",
            AccountNo: "blah",
            AmtActFore: "blah",
            AmtBudget: "blah",
            AmtVariance: "blah"
        }]
    }));
```

Please refer to [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/seyavi/1/edit?html,output) for a working example of your code, including the model initialisation part.

Comment: Yes !! Thank you so much !! Now that I have added following code & **it worked !!**   `var oTreeModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
          oTreeModel.setData(data);
          oTable.setModel(oTreeModel);
          oTable.bindItems("/root",oTemplate);`

Comment: Excellent Yal. Happy to hear that :)